# SVG being cut off outside parent container

Tags: html, css, svg

On my website, I have a CSS translate that allows to move up, down the parent element to expose div's that are outside user's view zone. I now added an SVG into the parent container on top of the other layers. But when the user clicks the button the element slides down/up to reveal an SVG being cut off outside the viewing area. The whole SVG just gets cut off outside of the home-section. Posting code that uses the SVG + container.

```css
.container {
  /* border: solid 1px red; */
  width: 300vw;
  height: 300vh;
  position: fixed;
  /* z-index: 10; */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(0, 0, 0);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.home-container {
  /* border: solid 5px green; */
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  /* transform: translate(-100vw, 0); */
}

.bg-home {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.bg-home img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.bg-move {
  animation: fade 6s ease-out alternate infinite;
}

.gradient-svg {
  overflow: visible;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  /* z-index: 11; */
}

.svg-path {
  width: 40%;
  height: 20%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: red solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container">
  <div class="gradient-svg">
    <svg class="svg-path" data-name="gradient-svg-path" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 2500 2500"><path d="M794.35 55.81S515.84-83.44 220.84 77.99v-.23S8.1 152.35.2 331.28c-7.78 176.27 214.04 282.48 220.71 285.63v.42s289.87 144.48 584.92-17.07v-.09c40.07-20.57 179-102.82 185-256.84 6.91-180.09-196.48-287.52-196.48-287.52zm-573.44 316.6l.29-.12-.29.21zm237.37 55.31c-24.08-17.68-50.6-99.06-110-102.41a107.69 107.69 0 00-14.69.2c95.81-38.71 220-85.63 234.61-74.93 24.08 17.68 50.59 99.07 110 102.42a113.42 113.42 0 0020.38-.78c-96.22 38.28-225.37 86.45-240.28 75.5z"/></svg>
  </div>
  <div class="home-container">
    <div class="bg-home bg-move">
      <img src="72ppi/Asset 3.png" alt="film">
    </div>
    <div class="nav-button-h text-fade">
      <p id="pressbtn">PRESS</p>
      <p id="logo-center">SHEK LEUNG</p>
      <p id="aboutbtn">ABOUT</p>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-button-v text-fade">
      <p id="colbtn">COLLECTION</p>
      <p id="projbtn">PROJECTS</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Looks like your viewBox isn't big enough.

Comment: I have tried to make the box bigger but the svg is still cut off - by that i meant i changed the second two values in the argument